# Code to get file size after upload and insert into table is not working

Tags: php, mysql, filesize

I have a MySQL/PHP project that currently has a files table that creates virtual folders and links to uploaded files, the upload and accessing works fine, however i have just added the field 'size' and have amended my code to update the file size after upload into the table, however the code is not working.  I get no errors and the file still gets uploaded but the code is inserting a null value into the relevant field.  Code is below:

```
global $dal;
$tblDocs = $dal->Table("doc_files");
$fileArray = my_json_decode($values["file"]);

for($i = 0; $i < count($fileArray); $i++)
{
$tblDocs->Value["parent_folder_id"]=$_SESSION["current_folder"];
$tblDocs->Value["file_type"]="file";
$tblDocs->Value["file"]=my_json_encode(array($fileArray[$i]));
$tblDocs->Value["hash"]=generatePassword(HASH_LENGTH);
$tblDocs->Value["name"]=$fileArray[$i]["usrName"];
$tblDocs->Value["ownerid"]=$_SESSION["user_id"];
$tblDocs->Value["created"]=now();
$tblDocs->Value["filesize"]=formatBytes($fileArray[0]["size"],2);

$tblDocs->Add();

}
```

Comment: tip: don't store your filesize as a string. you'll just end up hating yourself for doing so. Store it as an `int`, then format the int for human usage if/when needed.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong index:

```
$tblDocs->Value["name"]=$fileArray[$i]["usrName"];
                                   ^^--here you use the loop index

$tblDocs->Value["filesize"]=formatBytes($fileArray[0]["size"],2);
                                                   ^---hard-coded index
```

Comment: Ok I have changed it to   $tblDocs->Value["filesize"]=filesize($fileArray[$i]); and it still isnt working, please can someone give me an idiot proof way of inserting the filesize as an int

Comment: totally wrong as well. now you're passing an array of file data into filesize(). `$fileArray[$i]['size']` is probably all you needed. or whatever the parameter name is in that array. `var_dump($fileArray)` will probably tell you more.

Comment: All I want to do is use filesize($filename) as a simple foolproof code, but then it is the $filename value i am not sure about, i have not produced the code about so don't know anything about json, all i want is to get the $filename for current record